# Difference between kara/made から・まで vs kara/nikakete から・にかけて

Tags: particle-から

I will like to understand the difference between kara/made から・まで and kara/nikakete から・にかけて.

Are they supposed to mean the same thing?

Answer (score 9):

There is a fairly big and important difference between the two that makes it impossible for us to use them interchangeably all the time.

> 「AからBまで」 means "from A through B" when both Point A and Point B are defined clearly and precisely without hinting at a possible range either temporally or spatially.

「9[時]{じ}から15時までアルバイトをしています。」 = "I work part-time from 9:00 till 15:00."

「[東京]{とうきょう}から[横浜]{よこはま}まで[歩]{ある}いていった。」 = "I walked from Tokyo to Yokohama."

> 「AからBにかけて」 means "from around A through around B" with an implied range for both points either temporally or spatially.

「[深夜]{しんや}から[早朝]{そうちょう}にかけて[大雨]{おおあめ}となるでしょう。」 = "It is expected to rain heavily starting sometime late at night and ending sometime around early morning."

「[東北]{とうほく}から[関東]{かんとう}にかけて、[納豆]{なっとう}を[食]{た}べる[人]{ひと}が[多]{おお}い。」 = "From Touhoku through Kantou, you will find many people who eat natto."